# Multiple Modal Boxes in Partial View will not open at times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have three modal boxes in my Partial View.

1) runDates
2) errorCodes
3) testExceptions

The first two dialog boxes have ajax requests within them.  The ajax request in the second one would sort of disable the first and the third dialog box. When I click on the first and third, they will not open. If I do not use the second dialog box everything works perfect.

I also have seperate Javascript files for each modal box. Please suggest, I am just stumped on this one. Thanks in advance!

View

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runLogEntry.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var runlogListErrorsUrl = '@Url.Action("ListErrorCodes", "RunLogEntry")';

</script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Enter a new Run Log Entry</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div id="main">
            @Html.Partial("_RunLogEntryPartialView", Model)
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runDates.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/testexception.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="bodyContent">
    @if (Model.RunDatesDisplay != null && Model.RunDatesDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Run Dates")
        </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="RunDatesChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
            Click here to Select/View Run Dates</span>
            <br />
            <span id="RunDatesDisplayy" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">
            </span></span>
    }
</div>

<div id="runDatestreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 400px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <table class="grid" style="width: 600px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Run Dates:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Minimum Replicate:
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RunDatesDisplay)
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="bodyContent">
    @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null && Model.TestExceptionDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Test Exceptions")
        </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="TestExceptionChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
            Click here to View Test Exceptions</span>
            <br />
            <span id="TestExceptionDisplayy"></span></span>
    }
</div>
<div id="testExceptiontreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <table class="grid" style="width: 600px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Exception
                </th>
                <th>
                    Frequency
                </th>
                <th>
                    Comment
                </th>
                <th>
                    Replicate Range
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TestExceptionDisplay)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="bodyContent">
    <span class="leftContent">
        @Html.Label("Error Code")
    </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="ChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">Click
        here to Select Error Codes</span>
        <br />
        <span id="ErrorCodeDisplay" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">@(Model.ErrorDescription)</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ErrorDescription)
    </span>
</div>

<div id="treeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px; display:none;">
    <div id="errorCodes">
        @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), null, "e")
    </div>
    <div id="inputReps" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/errorCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Javascript file for treeview  Errorcodes**

```
var errorTextArea;
var ErrorCodeDialog;


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
    $("#errorCodes ul").treeview({
        collapsed: true,
        prerendered: false
    });


    ErrorCodeDialog = $("#treeview").dialog({ closeOnEscape: true, stack: false, autoOpen: false, modal: false, resizable: false, draggable: true, title: 'Select and input Error details', width: 480, height: 500,

        buttons: { Select: function () {
            var btnText = '';
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane :button').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == 'Select') {
                    btnText = 'Select';
                    $(this).text('Apply');
                    $("#errorCodes").attr("style", "display:none;");
                    $("#inputReps").attr("style", "display:inline;");
                }
                else if ($(this).text() == 'Apply') {
                    btnText = 'Apply';
                    $(this).text('Select');
                    $("#errorCodes").attr("style", "display:inline;");
                    $("#inputReps").attr("style", "display:none;");
                }
            });

            if (btnText == 'Select') {
                errorTextArea = "";
                $("#errorCodes :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                    var v = $(this).val();
                    if (errorTextArea.length > 0) {
                        errorTextArea = errorTextArea + " | ";
                    }
                    errorTextArea = errorTextArea + v;
                });
                if ($("#LogType").val() == "Run")
                //$("#inputReps").load("/RunLogEntry/ListErrorCodes", { ID: $("#ID").val(), ErrorCodes: errorTextArea });
                    $("#inputReps").load(runlogListErrorsUrl, { ID: $("#ID").val(), ErrorCodes: errorTextArea });
                else
                //$("#inputReps").load("/ServiceEntry/ListErrorCodes", { ID: $("#ID").val(), ErrorCodes: errorTextArea });
                    $("#inputReps").load(serviceListErrorsUrl, { ID: $("#ID").val(), ErrorCodes: errorTextArea });

            }
            else {
                errorTextArea = "";
                var i = 0;
                $("#inputReps :input").each(function () {
                    var v = $(this).val();
                    if (errorTextArea.length > 0) {

                        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'hidden')
                            errorTextArea = errorTextArea + ' | ' + v;
                        else {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                errorTextArea = errorTextArea + ' ~ L ' + v;
                                i = 1;
                            }
                            else {
                                errorTextArea = errorTextArea + ' ~ P ' + v;
                                i = 0;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                        errorTextArea = v;
                });

                if (errorTextArea.Length > 0) {
                    errorTextArea = errorTextArea.substr(0, errorTextArea.length - 1);
                }
                $("#ErrorCodeDisplay").text(errorTextArea);
                $("#ErrorDescription").val(errorTextArea);
                ErrorCodeDialog.dialog("close");
            }
        },
            Cancel: function () {
                ErrorCodeDialog.dialog("close");
                //                $(this).dialog("close");

                //                if ($(this).text() == 'Cancel') {
                //                    $(this).dialog("close");
                //                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('#ChildDialogLink').click(function () {
        $(ErrorCodeDialog).dialog("open");
        //        return ErrorCodeDialog.dialog('open');
        //replace the div id with the id of the button/form 


        //        $(ErrorCodeDialog).dialog("open"); 
    });
});
```

**Javascript file for runDatestreeview**

```
var RunDialog;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);

    RunDialog = $("#runDatestreeview").dialog({ closeOnEscape: true, stack: false, autoOpen: false,
        modal: false, resizable: true, draggable: true, title: 'Select Run Dates to Auto-Populate Form Fields & Test Exceptions:',
        width: 600, height: 500, position: 'center',
        //        open: function (type, data) {
        //        },
        buttons: { UpdatePage: function () {
            $.post("/RunLogEntry/LogFileConfirmation",
              $("#form").serialize(),
               function (data) {
                   $("#runDatestreeview").remove();
                   $("#testExceptiontreeview").remove();
                   $("#main").html(data);
                   $(RunDialog).dialog("close");
               }, "html");
        },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    RunDialog.closest("div.ui-dialog").appendTo("#form");

    $(document).on("click", "#RunDatesChildDialogLink", function () {
        //    $('#RunDatesChildDialogLink').click(function () {
        $(RunDialog).dialog("open");
    });

    //Region Auto-Open Modal Box
    var modalOpen = $("#LogModals").val();

    if (modalOpen == "0") {
        $("#runDatestreeview").dialog({ autoOpen: true });
    }
    //End Auto Open Modab Box Region

    //    $("#runDatestreeview").parent().appendTo("form");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried dialog("destroy") instead of dialog("close")?

Comment: I will try it now, but I do have to maintain the state of the content within the first two dialog boxes since they have a checkbox list.

Comment: I tried dialog destory but the problem is lets say I open the first one and create an ajax request and upon success I destroy the first dialog. Now the second dialog after its ajax request, the first dialog will not open.